# Chrome web driver not found after clean installation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried updating my chrome driver and selenium but cant locate driver anymore

I used to code on selenium webdriver however i didnt update it for about a year , when i tried to access the projects again the webdrivers and selenium were outdated. I did install the newest versions of chrome drivers (same as the chrome version im having) and installed the newest selenium webdriver jars. but everytime i tried to run it i kept getting this error msg
""Error: Unable to initialize main class test.test.nagwa
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver""
after searching i figured its a problem with selenium not being able to locate the chrome driver , I am 100% sure that the path chromedriver.exe is correct and i reinstalled eclipse ide and still nth

Comment: please, could you give more details? what do you mean with install? are you running a jar from your local? running in a CI/CD pipeline through some tool like jenkins? deploying in a remote server to be executed with some frequency? add details about how the project is being built (such as using a build like maven), the commands used to execute the code, error messages returned, etc. If it is possible provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)